# Padding of a certain percentage of screen width

Tags: html, css, margin, percentage

I have a main container div, and I'd like it to be margined from the top of the screen exactly, for example, `10%` of the screen width. This way I won't have problems with non-uniform screen sizes etc..

I already found a dirty workaround which is putting a `1px by 1px` image of the color of the background, right before the div, and then style it to have `10%` of the width of the screen. But this looks quite dirty, doesn't it? Is there any better solution?

Comment: What did you tried, Can you show your code.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I find very elegant is to insert the page in a table, beginning right after the body, and terminating right before it.

You'd have this:

```
<html>
<head><title>...</title></head>
<body>
<table id="content"><tr><td>

    Your whole page comes here...

</td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Now simply decide the size of the page, using the style:

```
#content {

    width: 850px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}
```

Comment: But surely this is a terrible idea as tables are not meant to be used for layout purposes the way they were 10+ years ago. Tables should only be used to display tabular data.

Comment: I really see no problem whatsoever in using a table with this purpose: it's a totally cross-browser solution; it requires no tricksy enchants  to make it work; and it does work. Not using something simply because it's old is actually the only terrible thing I'm able to see here.

Comment: Here's one of my favourite posts on why not to use tables for layout. I hope it helps change your opinion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html

Comment: Thanks for the refers; I'll read the arguments presented later, but I'm quite sure using a table on this particular purpose is not something to be avoided -- mainly considering images were being added from side to side of the page in order to center it.

Comment: I honesty can't believe this has been accepted as an answer. Kudos Rubens.

Comment: This is simply what I have to present here, the best I can make from myself; if you think it's all that bad, I'm quite sure you have a better solution for it, and I'm also quite sure Matteo Monti will gladly accept your answer as the correct one. Why don't you post it?

Comment: Alternative answer posted below.

Answer (score 3):

Same solution as Rubens without using tables. I've also placed some code to deal with the top margin you were asking about but using padding instead.

```
<html>
 <head>
 <title>...</title></head>
 <body>
  <div id="content">
   Your whole page comes here...
  </div>
 </body>
</html>


* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

html, body {
    height:100%;
}

body {
    padding:10% 0 0;
}

#content {
    width: 850px; // replace with your desired width
    margin:0 auto;
}
```